# C# Get control at cursor

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for a way to get a control at where my cursor is pointing to, is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: in a textbox.. listbox ?

Comment: Like WinSpyXX from VS installs? Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx as it talks how to find windows and check properties with managed code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [GetChildAtPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6zktd23%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method. Combine it with a handler for the [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)  or [MouseHover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) event and you have your control under the cursor.